# Modifying elements of a string vector in c++

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

How can I append a string to an element of an string vector?
I consistently get segmentation fault.

Comment: Please provide us with more details.

Comment: There are no doubt many posts on this site that would answer your question, but if you want to keep your question open, you should post the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appending `str` to the `i`th element of `vec`:

```
vec[i] += str;
```

Assuming `vec` is something like a `std::vector<std::string>` and the `i`th element exists.

Comment: Problem is the existence of the i'th element of the vector. Although I should have use push_back(string x), I just tried assigning string value to the unallocated i'th element of the vector.